# Measurable function - integral of square integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have an easy question, but I don't know how to show the answer.

Let $f \in L^2([0, \infty)$, show that the function $$[0, \infty) \ni t \mapsto \int_{0}^{t}f(s) \ ds$$ 
is a measurable function.

The function is measurable if its pre-image is measurable, in this case we have a function from $[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}$, so we take an arbitrary borel set $E \subset C$, and we consider the set 
$$\{ t \in [0, \infty) : \int_{0}^{t}f(s) \ ds \in E \}.$$

How to show that $$\ell (\{ t \in [0, \infty) : \int_{0}^{t}f(s) \ ds \in E \}) < \infty?$$

Is the above measure just
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,t)}(s) f(s) ds dt $$
and since $\chi_{[0,t)} \cdot f$ is measurable then by Fubini theorem 
we have that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds dt = t \int_{0}^{\infty}f(s)\ ds$, but we know that $f \in L^2([0, \infty))$, not $L^1([0, \infty))$ so we cannot conclude whether this set is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that $f\in L^2[0,\infty)$ to show that $g:t\mapsto\int_0^tf$ is continuous. In particular, it is measurable.

Indeed, for $s_1<s_2$
$$
|g(s_2)-g(s_1)|=\left|\int_{s_1}^{s_2}f\right|\leq\int_{s_1}^{s_2}|f|=\int_{\mathbb R}\,1_{(s_1,s_2)}\,|f|\\ \leq\|f\|_2\,\left(\int_{\mathbb R}1_{(s_1,s_2)}\right)^{1/2}=\|f\|_2\,(s_2-s_1)^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Or even easier, if $f$ is nonnegative then the integral is a monotone function of $t$ – obviously measurable. In general write $f=f^+-f^-$ and apply the first case.